# Mutual Information in a Binary Erasure Channel

Tags: information-theory

Imagine a Binary Erasure Channel as depicted on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_erasure_channel).

One equation describing the mutual information is following:

```
I(x;y) 
 = H(x) - H(x|y) 
 = H(x) - p(y=0) • 0 - p(y=?) • H(x) -p(y=1) • 0
```

Why is it "`p(y=?) • H(x)" and not "p(y=?) • H(x|y=?)`"?

Answer (score 0):

### It can be proved using Bayes' theorem.

The channel:

```
x           y
     1-f
0 --------> 0
 \
  \    f
   +------> ?
  /
 /   1-f
1---------> 1
```

Let input distribution be `P(x) = {p(x=0)=g; p(x=1)=1-g}`
Then:

```
p(x=0/y=?) = p(y=?/x=0) * p(x=0) / p(y=?)
p(x=0/y=?) = (f * g) / (f * g - f * (1 - g)) = g;
p(x=1/y=?) = p(y=?/x=1) * p(x=1) / p(y=?)
p(x=1/y=?) = (f * (1 - g)) / (f * g - f * (1 - g)) = 1 - g;
```

As result:

```
p(x=0/y=?) = p(x=0)
p(x=1/y=?) = p(x=1)
```

From the defenitions of entropy and conditional entropy:

```
H(X) = p(x=0) * log(1 / p(x=0)) + p(x=1) * log(1 / p(x=1))
H(X/y=?) = p(x=0/y=?) * log(1 / p(x=0/y=?)) + p(x=1/y=?) * log(1 / p(x=1/y=?))
```

So:

`H(X) = H(X/y=?)`